# How can I determine the limit on Vertex Shader outputs?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I'm trying to introduce multiple shadow casters, and in the process I'm passing a transformed position for each light in the VS output. The shader compiler reports errors as a result of the output size exceeding some internal limit, but I've been thus far unable to determine what the limit actually is (or how to find it).

The output structure is as follows:

```
out VS_OUT
{
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec3 Colour;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    vec4[MAX_SHADOW_CASTERS] LightSpaceFragPos;
} vso;
```

Compilation has failed at MAX_SHADOW_CASTERS value 64 and 32, at the very least.

Additionally, any suggestions around improving the capacity of the array would be appreciated. These values are naturally per fragment, so a universal texture/buffer would be impractical as far as I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of *varying* vector variables (that's what the interface between the vertex and fragment shader stages are called - and in earlier GLSL versions those actually had the keyword `varying` instead of `in`/`out`) can be queryied via `glGetIntegerv` with `GL_MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` as the `pname` parameter argument.

Comment: Thanks, knowing the name is very helpful! I’ll probably have to make another question for this, but do you know of any way to work around this? The limit appears to be restrictively tiny for what I’m attempting to do.

Comment: @CalvinSoueid: Then what you're attempting to do probably isn't going to work out the way you want it to.